# Call to undefined method in fuel PHP

Tags: php, fuelphp

I'm extremely new to fuel PHP and I really don't know how to fix my error:

I downloaded the .zip file of fuel php then I extracted them and put the contents in C:\wamp\www. Then I started working through [This tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-fuel-php-framework--net-21334). These were the last codes I wrote:

```
//C:\wamp\www\fuelphp\fuel\app\classes\controller\hello2.php
<?php
class Controller_Hello2 extends Controller {
public function action_index()
{
echo "Hello World!";
}
public function action_buddy($name = 'buddy')
{
$this->response->body = View::factory('hello', array(
'name' => $name,
));
}
}
?>

//C:\wamp\www\fuelphp\fuel\app\views\hello2.php
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<p>Hey <?php echo $name ?>, how's it going?</p>
```

However when I run hello2.php I'm getting this:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
> Call to undefined method Fuel\Core\View::factory() APPPATH/classes/controller/hello2.php @ line 9

I understand the meaning, but I absolutely don't know why and how to fix this. What should I do?

Comment: check the spellings and capitals... undefined method means it did not find it.. try putting the full paths as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tutorial must be old, `factory` was deprecated and now removed, use `forge()` instead

```
$this->response->body = View::forge('hello', array(
'name' => $name,
));
```

Comment: meda is correct. `factory()` is an old deprecated method. There are rather a large number of out of date tutorials for fuel but that is slowly starting to change. I'd recommend checking the official fuelphp documentation. http://fuelphp.com/docs